# How can I update remote data list when data updated?

Tags: navigation, android-jetpack-compose

[image]

1. Select in A Screen
2. navigate to B Screen
3. edit the product info in B Screen
4. push Save Button, when update success, navigate up to A Screen
5. A Screen show update list

**Screen**

```
sealed class Screen (
    val route: String
) {
    object List: Screen("product_list") //-->A Screen
    object EditProduct: Screen("edit_product") //-->B Screen
}
```

**NavHost in MainActivity onCreate**

```
        NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Screen.Splash.route) {
            
            composable(route = Screen.List.route) { 
                ListScreen()
            }
            composable(route = Screen.EditProduct.route) {
                EditProductScreen()
            }
```

A is a screen that brings up remote data and represents the list, and B contains detailed information about the product selected from A.

After entering the information about the product in B, I would like to update the list of A to show the revised information when I return to A by navigate up.

In this case, how should I deal with it?

---

```
LaunchedEffect(true) {
    viewModel.eventFlow.collectLatest { event ->
        when(event) {
            is UiEvent.SaveTask -> {
                //previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set<Boolean>("save_result", true)
                onSave()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when I called onSave() --navcontroller::popBackStack,
navigate to A Screen, but list isn't update

Answer (score 0):

You cal pass a callback to your `EditProductScreen` and call `navController.popBackStack()` along with your list update code in this callback.

```
@Composable
fun EditProductScreen(onSave: () -> Unit) {
    Button(onClick = onSave) {
    }
}
```

```
composable(route = Screen.EditProduct.route) {
    EditProductScreen(
        onSave = {
            navController.popBackStack()
            // update your list
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: I tried with popbackstack, but A Screen is doesn't update list.

Comment: @PolarisNation then you should add the code of how you're trying to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to deal with reloading data from other screen.

On the ViewModel of Main screen, create a state to storing reload map.

```kotlin
class MainViewModel() : ViewModel() {

    private val _reloadMap: MutableStateFlow<MutableMap<String, Boolean>> = MutableStateFlow(hashMapOf())

    val reloadMap: StateFlow<MutableMap<String, Boolean>> = _reloadMap

    fun triggerReload(key: String) {
        _reloadMap.value = reloadMap.value.apply {
            put(key, true)
        }
    }

    fun markReloaded(key: String) {
        _reloadMap.value = reloadMap.value.apply {
            put(key, false)
        }
    }
}
```

Declare MainViewModel on Composable that defined NavHost, and pass this ViewModel to composables that need to be connected

```kotlin
val viewModel: MainViewModel = viewModel()
composable(route = Screen.List.route) { 
    ListScreen(viewModel)
}
composable(route = Screen.EditProduct.route) {
    EditProductScreen(viewModel)
}
```

In `EditProductScreen` call `triggerReload()` with a key when data is saved

```kotlin
mainViewModel.triggerReload("list_screen")
```

In `ListScreen` collect the reloadMap to reload data after received reload key

```kotlin
LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
    mainViewModel.reloadMap.asyncCollect(this) { map ->
        if (map.getOrDefault("list_screen", false)) {
            viewModel.reloadList()
            mainViewModel.markReloaded("list_screen")
        }
    }
}


// asyncCollect func:
fun <T> SharedFlow<T>.asyncCollect(scope: CoroutineScope, onCollected: (T) -> Unit) {
    scope.launch {
        collectLatest {
            onCollected(it)
        }
    }
}
```